# Mass term in QCD is not hermitian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, fermions, quantum-chromodynamics

Accordingly to the result

$$
(\bar{\psi}\psi)^\dagger = (-1)\bar{\psi}\psi
\tag1$$

coming from the fact that fields with and without bar anti-commutes, you can deduce that the QCD mass term

$$
-m\bar{\psi}\psi, \quad m \in \mathbb{R}
\tag2$$

is not hermitian, so QCD Lagrangian is not. Nevertheless, it has to be hermitian since we have the scattering matrix to be unitary. What is happening here?

Comment: It remains unsolved in that post that I didn't see when I asked mine, so if someone has any idea, I'll appreaciate it

Comment: Hi, if you write out the fields in terms of weyl spinors, you get terms $\epsilon ^{ab} \psi_a \chi_b$. Applying the hermitian conjugate to those terms changes the position of $\chi $ and $\psi$. If you move the terms back to the original position you get one minus sign from the anti-commutation, and one from the epsilon

Comment: Forget about matrix and stuff, if you look at the individual terms in the mass, they look like $iab$, where a and b are *real* Grassmann numbers. Then $(iab)^\dagger = i^\dagger b^\dagger a^\dagger = -iba = iab$, therefore Hermitian. In math jargon, mass is valued in imaginary ring.

Comment: @MadMax What do you think about my answer to this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476641/cpt-transformation-for-bilinears ? It's quite related to what we are discussing here and in the answer I think that I get to prove that transpose and adjoint of bilinears just swap order but not introduce signs. Everything looks fine, but a second opinion is always useful

Comment: @Vicky, as you mention there, the definition $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$ does not involve any extra sign, regardless of A/B being real or Grassmann, while the fact that the mass term is valued in imaginary (the $i$) ring (the $ab$) is a bit hard to swallow for beginners.

Comment: @MadMax Yes, but the problem is that I've seen some posts about this issues that assert that transpose not only reverses order but introduces a minus sign while adjoint just reverses. See comments on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203019/why-is-the-dirac-mass-term-hermitian-if-grassmann-valued-fields-anticommute/203033?noredirect=1#comment1071504_203033